# Remove posts from WordPress loop if the date in the post is equal to today's date

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, date

I could be wording this very badly. So I have a series of posts from a CPT called "Upcoming Games". I am using Advanced Custom Fields to set the release date for each game. Now, when the date of that game is equal to today's date I want it to do something. I have two scenario's, but would like to go with, for now, whatever is easiest.

Scenario #1 = draft that post

Scenario #2* = remove that post from the loop so it doesn't appear in the front-end, so it's still published

*my ideal choice

This is part of my loop here:

```
$time = current_time( 'timestamp' ); // Get current unix timestamp

$cpt_posts_per_page = ( is_front_page() ) ? 4 : -1;
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$args = array(
        'post_type'                 => 'upcoming-games',
        'post_status'               => 'publish',
        'orderby'                   => 'meta_value',
        'meta_key'                  => 'release_date',
        'meta_value'                => $time,
        'meta_compare'              => '>=',
        'order'                     => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page'            => $cpt_posts_per_page,
        'paged'                     => $paged
    );

    $upcoming_games = new WP_Query( $args );

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can not test now, but You can get some idea from this.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );

function custom_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {

    if ( ! $q->is_main_query() ) return;
    if ( ! $q->is_post_type_archive() ) return;

    if ( ! is_admin() && (is_blog() || is_archive()) ) {

        $q->set( 'date_query', array(array(
            'year'  => date("Y"),
            'month' => date("m"),
            'day'   => date("d"),
            'inclusive' => false
        )));

    }

    remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );
```

In your code too you could have used

```
 $arg = array( 'date_query' => array(
            'year'  => date("Y"),
            'month' => date("m"),
            'day'   => date("d"),
            'inclusive' => false
        ) )
```

as WP_Query() parameter.

Comment: sorry, when I meant today's date I just meant whatever day is today/current, not January 4, 2017.

Comment: so I have only given an example, you can replace that by real condition, updated that, I was expecting you to understand it and implement it.

Comment: would I place this into my functions.php?

Comment: @DarrenBachan if you are unable to understand it, better to spend some time in codex. with out understanding it you can use it, yes you can place it inside functions.php but depending on your situation, you may like to modify it little bit . if you find it helpful do not forget to upvote.